# Visual Basic .Net Rounding Issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am building a unit converter with Visual Basic and Visual Studio 2012. I am using the conversion rate of 1 inch = 0.0833333 feet for the inch to foot conversion. When I type in 12 inches, it gives me an answer of 0.9999996 instead of 1. How can I fix this problem?

The issue is with the inch to foot conversion below.

```
            ' converts inch to...
            If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                If cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                    ' meter
                    txtUnit2.Text = (dblUnit1 * 0.0254).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                    ' millimeter
                    txtUnit2.Text = (dblUnit1 * 25.4).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                    ' foot
                    txtUnit2.Text = (dblUnit1 * 0.0833333).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                    ' inch
                    txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
                End If
            End If
```

Comment: Post the code that is doing the conversion.

Comment: Standard reference material for these kinds of questions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a rounded result, use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(12 * 0.0833333))
```

prints 1.

Comment: I used the Math.Round  and it worked for 12 inches to foot, but then when I try to convert 1 inch to foot I get 0.

Comment: Math.Round(value, 6) worked. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You could try calculating your conversion number at runtime, you shouldn't lose any precision that way..

```
    Dim twelveInches As Double = 12.0
    Dim oneInchValue As Double = 1.0 / twelveInches
    Console.WriteLine(oneInchValue.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} x {1} = {2}", oneInchValue, twelveInches, oneInchValue * twelveInches))
```

Output:

```
0.0833333333333333
0.0833333333333333 x 12 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I type in 12 inches, it gives me an answer of 0.9999996 instead of 1

0.0833333 * 12 = 0.9999996

Put that into Windows Calculator and you'll get the same result. What did you expect?

Try defining your constant with an expression:

```
Const inch As Decimal = 1D / 12D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my  final, working code.

```
                            ' converts inch to...
            If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                If cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                    ' meter
                    txtUnit2.Text = (dblUnit1 * 0.0254).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                    ' millimeter
                    txtUnit2.Text = (dblUnit1 * 25.4).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                    ' foot
                    txtUnit2.Text = (dblUnit1 * (1 / 12)).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                    ' inch
                    txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
                End If
            End If
```